# MDM with CCS in Android

Tags: android, google-play, google-apps, mdm

I am looking for a MDM solution for android devices. My primary aim is to push apps from GooglePlay into the company owned android devices preferably without prompting the user. I worked with iOS devices for last few weeks and implemented a MDM solution with APNS. Where the  server sends a wakeup command to the device after which the configuration profile looks up for MDM server and executes the specified command like app installation. I found CCS to be little synchronous to APNS. Am I on the right path?

On browsing through the web I struck up on this site stating the device administration. The sample code link available on this site is not working. Is there any open-source Android MDM available?

After enrolment is it possible to install app in google play without prompting the user?

Answer (score 2):

Without Prompting any third party MDM's or app's can't Install apk in device , Only Plastore App have this option to install silently , You can just create a notification To the user to Install perticular app (On clickng It redirect to playstore using Intents) , Repeat your Notifier Until user/emplyee Installs Application from market by using package name , There are few open source MDM available **WSo2** Is the one [here](http://wso2.com/) And also you cant provision Using URL in android without your app Installed , Ask user to give Uniqe ID for Provision first time After Installation